# How to create a user with just First name, Last name and emai. And not with the username

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

Is there any way to create a user without the username? I tried doing this by first_name, last_name, password and email. But got an error:

```
TypeError at /accounts/register/
create_user() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

So, I searched for creating so, and then found that django needs a username. But I hope there is some other way around. Can anyone please guide me through if there is. Thank you.

Comment: which version of django?

Comment: You can use an email address for the username. If you want to enforce that the field is an email field, you can use the built-in create user form and override the username CharField with an EmailField.

Comment: @karthikr I'm using Django 1.5

Comment: @Brandon yes, that's exactly what i want to do. Can you point me to any tutorials is possible.

Comment: Sure. Are you using the built-in user creation form from django.contrib.auth?

Comment: No. I am using from forms. Do I have to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a custom user model you can subclass `UserCreationForm` and override the `username` field as such:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username',)

    username = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=255)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = user.username
        user.save()
        return user
```

Now you have a `UserCreationForm` that will validate and use an email address for the username, in addition to setting the email field to the username automatically to keep them in sync. This doesn't set the `password` field, which you would need to do as well. Change as you need, hope that gets you going.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!!! But, now I made some changes in the login template, and Changed 'username' to 'email', and also in the views. But now when I tried to login, it tells me that my login details are incorrect. Any help please.

Comment: Sorry, my bad again! LOL! In the views, I even changed authentication to email, so it was looking for email, and not the username. Just one more thing, can I do the form validation with this form???

Comment: I wanted to check whether the emai alredy exists or not in the database.

Comment: Do I create another clean validation for it, or it is pre_defined in the UserCreationForm??? And one more thing, Can I create extra field with it? Eg: A choice field for gender.

Comment: Ah, in the case of unique, just add unique=True to the field. I've updated the example. You can always add a gender field to the form, but you would need to handle the persistence of the data yourself.

Comment: Okay, got it! Can I override the error message as well? Because, now it displaying the error as: `A user with that username already exists`. Can I override it to `email` and not `username`?

Comment: Sure. Just add the value in the `error_message` property for the field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages

Comment: I tried the way you told me, everythings fine. Just that, when I add `unique=True`, it gives me an error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique'`. I have posted this problem with details in the different [forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330314/typeerror-when-tried-to-override-the-usercreationforms-error-message), will you please kindly look into the probolem. Thank you.

Comment: My bad. The UserCreationForm isn't a model form.

Comment: Yup! Guess I'll just have to go with it any how. Thanks though!

Comment: The username field in the User model already has a unique validator on it, so you shouldn't need to specify it again.

Comment: Just keep in mind Django's User username field is 30 character max. If you anticipate longer email addresses, you should probably go the custom  user (and user manager) route.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can override the default User model by substituting a custom User model . Here is the details [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Sample code: models.py

```
if django.VERSION >= (1, 5):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

#Identifier is e-mail instead of user ID
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. But I am sorry. I am noob. I didn't quite understood what was there as how to achieve it. Can you please elaborate.