# TypeError when tried to override the UserCreationForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a registration form from UserCreationForm, to which I had override with the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username',)

    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': _("A user with that email already exists."),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }    

    username = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=250, unique=True)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = user.username
        user.save()
        return user
```

But I was getting an error:

```
NameError at /admin/
name '_' is not defined
```

So, I had to import

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

And that solved that problem. But now, after that has been fixed (i guess..that was the solution for the first problem), I am getting another error:

```
TypeError at /admin/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unique'
```

If I remove 'unique' from the `EmailField`, everything works fine. So, do I remove the `unique=true` from the form? Will it always be unique for each username(here its email), even though I remove it? And one more thing, was `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _` the suited solution for the error name `'_' is not defined`??? I am a newbie in django. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique` is not a parameter for `forms.EmailField`. You are confusing it with model field I guess.

And you want to use email field for username? If thats the case, try this:

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength':75}),
                         label=_("Email"))
```

And as to your query for "name '_' is not defined" :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

This is from django.contrib.auth.forms code.

Comment: Ok, will it always be unique? And what's the difference between `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _` and `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

Comment: Whether a field is unique or not, is to be determined while defining the model, not in the form. Since you are using auth.User model here, it will be taken care that its unique. I'm not sure about the exact difference between `gettext` and `ugettext_lazy`, I suggested to use it because it has been used in the corresponding forms.py in django :) . You can know more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160770/when-shoud-i-use-ugettext-lazy)

Comment: Okay! Got it! Guess I can carry on now. Thanks as well as for the nice explanation!

Comment: One more thing though. How do I add another field if I wanted to, say an option for 'choice(M/F/O)' or a field for 'date of birth' within this form? Do I need to make another model for it or I can just add a form field here itself???

Comment: @Robin You can add as many fields you like in the form, and they'll show up in the template. But where will they get saved? So yes, you need to add the field in some model. Since, the fields are related to a User, you can create a Profile model and set it to `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in setting file. In Django 1.5, [extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) has been introduced.